# The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T> in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following method and getting the following error. I wonder how could I able to overcome on this issue.

> The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task

```
private static async T GoRequest<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, HttpMethod method,string body = "")
            where T : class
{
      // the rest of the code I commented.
      // the following is the return
      var jsonResult = content.Replace(@"\", "").Trim('"');
                    return typeof (T) == typeof (string)
                        ? jsonResult as T
                        : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResult);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your return type in a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private static async Task<T> GoRequest<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, HttpMethod method, string body = "")
    where T : object
```

Answer (score 2):

The rule is simple: if your "regular" synchronous method would return `T`, your `async` method must return `Task<T>`:

```
private static async Task<T> GoRequest<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, HttpMethod method,string body = "")
        where T : class
```

You don't need to change anything else: when your `async` code returns a `T`, the compiler makes sure that the result is actually a `Task<T>`.

**Note:** Since your `async` method has no `await`s in it, you might as well change it to a "regular", synchronous, method.