# How to read a file in UWP with Windows.Storage

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp

I currently use this function to write to files:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
WriteToFile<List<Class>>(classesArray, sampleFile);

public static async void WriteToFile<T>(T objectToWrite, StorageFile file) where T : new()
{
    TextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
        writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}
```

So I assumed I could just do this for reading the same file:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
classesArray = ReadFromFile(sampleFile);

public static async T ReadFromFile<T>(StorageFile file) where T : new()
{
    TextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
}
```

**But it says "The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable, or IAsyncEnumerator"**

I assume there is an easy solution but I am relatively new to c# and UWP so haven't got a clue.

Comment: Pretty much identical to [The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231998/the-return-type-of-an-async-method-must-be-void-task-or-taskt-in-c-sharp). Note that this isn't really a Windows.Storage issue; it's a C# language issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you should modify both methods to be properly `async`. Currently the first method is `async void` which is an anti-pattern - all asynchronous methods should return a `Task`-like type unless they are event handlers (in which case you really have no other choice than `async void`).

Using `Task` as return type is important as in case of `async void` you are doing something called "fire-and-forget", meaning if during the execution of the method something fails and throws exception, it will be lost and you will never know the method in fact failed. Instead, if a method returns a `Task`, the exception will be wrapped in this task. After that it will automatically be rethrown when you `await` the method. In addition, when a "fire-and-forget" method execution reaches first "real" `await` the calling thread will see this as if the method has already completed and will continue executing the next statement. This is usually not what you want.

So you should edit the first method's header as follows:

```
public static async Task WriteToFileAsync<T>(T objectToWrite, StorageFile file) 
      where T : new()
{
   ...
}
```

And the second method's header as follows:

```
public static async Task<T> ReadFromFileAsync<T>(StorageFile file) 
     where T : new()
{
   ...
}
```

Notice I have added a `Async` suffix to the method names to make it clear they are asynchronous and should be awaited (this is a C# convention).

Finally, when you now call the methods, you should `await` them:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
await WriteToFileAsync<List<Class>>(classesArray, sampleFile);
```

And

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("test.txt");
classesArray = await ReadFromFileAsync(sampleFile);
```